# Detecting sibling divs enclosed by position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been asked to write a prototype application where a user lassos important locations on a background image inside a div frame. My approach is Photoshop-like, drawing divs of dynamic size and position into the DOM within the frame. But, my next step is where I need help.

I need to allow the user to select groups of lasso divs. These will be used by another function. The "tailingdiv" is a plain 1px border div that will be mouse drawn to enclose some of its sibling divs. The challenge is **detecting which divs are positioned inside the "tailingdiv"**! In other words, I may need to compare the xy coordinates of these divs and determine which ones are **visibly inside** the tailingdiv in spite of it being sibling in the DOM tree. As a bonus, I would like to work in some fudge factor for cases where a div is 75% inside the tailingdiv.

```
<div class="frame" id="lassoFrame" style="display: block; height: 333px; width: 500px; background-image: url("dump-1459285968.png"); background-size: 500px 333px;">
<div class="lasso ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; left: 96px; top: 263px; width: 320px; height: 35px;" coords="{"x1":96,"x2":416,"y1":263,"y2":298}"></div>
<div class="lasso ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; left: 62px; top: 8px; width: 89px; height: 46px;" coords="{"x1":62,"x2":151,"y1":8,"y2":54}"></div>
<div class="nudgeControl lasso ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; left: 161px; top: 14px; width: 88px; height: 40px;" coords="{"x1":161,"x2":249,"y1":14,"y2":54}"></div>
<div class="tailingdiv" style="position: absolute; left: 51px; top: 4px; width: 388px; height: 71px;" coords="{"x1":162,"x2":249,"y1":13,"y2":56}"></div>
</div>
```

It may look something like this. We have a background where someone has mouse drawn a set of lassos and they want to draw the tailingdiv to enclose the top two lasso divs. Upon drawing the tailingdiv (mouseup event), I need to examine the coordinates of these objects and determine which divs are visually positioned inside the tailingdiv.

[image]

Comment: You mean rectangle collision or rectangle inclusion?

Comment: I don't know. Define these terms.

Comment: for example if tailingdiv overlaps the corner of a lasso div, do you take it into consideration, or does it have to be completely inside tailingdiv?

Comment: If possible, I'd like some fudge factor -- meaning if the lasso div is MOSTLY inside the tailingdiv, I want it detected. If that is too much, I will accept it being completely inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that assumes your want to select all divs with class lasso that touch or collide with the div with class tailingdiv:

```
function getBox(elem) {
    elem=$(elem);
    var ofs=elem.offset();
    return {
        x:ofs.left,
        y:ofs.top,
        width:elem.width(),
        height:elem.height()
    };
}
function collide(elem1, elem2) {
  var a=getBox(elem1);
  var b=getBox(elem2);
  return (Math.abs(a.x - b.x) * 2 < (a.width + b.width)) &&
         (Math.abs(a.y - b.y) * 2 < (a.height + b.height));
}
$(function() {
    var tail=$('.tailingdiv');
    var divs=$('div.lasso').filter(function() {
        return collide(tail,this);
    });
    console.log(divs);
});
```

Since you need the entire box, you might consider using getBoundingClientRect() instead of the classic jQuery functions.

Here is the code for using getBoundingClientRect and also specifying a minimal overlap percentage (value between 0 and 1. If omitted it will default to 0.7. Set it to 0 to use it as in the previous example - strict collision):

```
function getBox(elem) {
    var e=$(elem);
    if (e.length==0||e.length>1) throw 'getBox accepts only one element as argument';
    var rect=e[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x:rect.left,
        y:rect.top,
        width:rect.width,
        height:rect.height
    };
}
function collide(elem1, elem2, overlap) {
  if (typeof(overlap)=='undefined') overlap=0.7;
  var a=getBox(elem1);
  var b=getBox(elem2);
  var area=Math.max(0, Math.min(a.x+a.width, b.x+b.width) - Math.max(a.x, b.x)) * Math.max(0, Math.min(a.y+a.height, b.y+b.height) - Math.max(a.y, b.y))
  return area/(b.width*b.height)>overlap;
}
```

And here is an example of jQuery integration and use:

```
$.fn.overlappedBy=function(elem,overlap) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        return collide(elem,this,overlap);
    });
}
$(function() {
    var tail=$('.tailingdiv');
    var divs=$('div.lasso').overlappedBy('.tailingdiv',0.3);
    console.log(divs);
});
```